# Reactjs, Webpack not working on IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I am getting this error in IE when I try run my react site. It works in all other browsers and I have tried to load babel-polyfill multiple ways.

IE 11 error:

[image]

Here is my webpack.dev.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{   
      test: /\.js$/, 
      enforce: "pre", 
      exclude: /node_modules/, 
      use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
      }
      }]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
      }]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
          }
      }]
  }]
  },
};
```

I just can't seem to fix this error any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do your React components have the extension `.jsx`? If so, try modifying your webpack test to `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/`, otherwise they aren't getting picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I didn't really post enough information for anyone to fix this as the problem didn't reside in the webpack.dev.config.js file. The problem resided in one of my React files:

```
publicIP().then(ip =>{
   //code here
});
```

As IE doesn't have support for ES6 the => was causing the error!